# convert macOS drawRect to iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Here is code from Mac OS X. I want to convert them to iOS.

```objectivec
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    NSGraphicsContext *gc = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
    [gc setShouldAntialias:YES];

    NSAffineTransform *trans;

    if ([NSGraphicsContext currentContextDrawingToScreen]) {
        trans = [NSAffineTransform transform];
        [trans scaleXBy:zoom yBy:zoom];
        [trans concat];
    }

    if ([NSGraphicsContext currentContextDrawingToScreen]) {
        trans = [NSAffineTransform transform];
        [trans translateXBy:0 yBy:10.0];
        [trans concat];
    }
}
```

how can *NSAffineTransform* convert to *CGAffineTransform*

Thanks for your help~

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CGAffineTransform`.

```objectivec
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformIdentity; // identity transfrom
CGAffineTransformScale(trans, 1.0/zoom, 1.0/zoom); // scale
```